# Enable Whoops error console within Laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling, whoops

I'm new to using Laravel 5.0. I use Laravel on my web server and prefer to use it there instead of locally. In tutorials, I've seen that there's a nice debugger (called "Whoops", if I'm not mistaken). It looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/mig0n9xz5/

However, my error page currently looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/p1cdol87p/

How can I configure Laravel to use the nicer error console?

Comment: Check app/config/app.php. Is debug mode set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.0 does not come with Whoops error handling. Instead it uses the default error display from Symfony. You have the `debug` key in the `/config/app.php` set as `true` so you see the error track (`FatalErrorException ...` in your image).

Hope it will be added in the next subversions or you could use one of this simple workarounds:

- https://github.com/guidovanbiemen/laravel-whoops
- https://mattstauffer.co/blog/bringing-whoops-back-to-laravel-5